# Does Ascetic Style work with Amulet of Mighty Fists and Magic Fang?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The wording of [Ascetic Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/ascetic-style-combat-style) is interesting because it says,

> you can apply the effects of feats that have Improved Unarmed Strike
>   as a prerequisite, as well as effects that augment an unarmed strike,
>   as if attacks with the weapon were unarmed attacks.

I am wondering how far this “effects that augment an unarmed strike” extend. Does it work with [Magic Fang](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-fang/) and things like the [Amulet of Mighty Fists](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text seems to be quite clear on the matter. As it is written, it applies to any effect. This includes feats(like weapon focus), magic items(like the amulet of mighty fists) and spells(like magic fang).

Comment: I was afraid that this is the case :D I sort of hoped that there is an errata for the amulet of mighty fists, because so far for me it seems a bit broken that you can hold two magic weapons (kukris for the crit for example) which are also affected by your permanent (or temporary) greater magic fang and your amulet of mighty fists.

Comment: consider the price (and, depending on GM ruling) the rarity of a AoMF, and it's not THAT broken anymore. the +1 amulet is probably affordable by a mid-level adventurer, but anything beyond that ... you might have to plunder a dragons hoard before you can afford it. and even if you could afford it, you still have to find a shop that sells it... or find a wizard willing to craft it, which might be an adventure of its own. Always consider rarity/price + availability!